# Use Submit button to send form data to an email

Tags: html, submit, mailto

I was browsing around the internet and created this consensus form. the layout and everything is as I want it.What Id Like to do is when the user clicks the submit button I would like the contents of the form to be sent to an email for example somemail@mail.com

Can anyone help me please.This would be very useful to me. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>GoodJob - BadJob - Tenerife</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Good - Bad - hmm</a></h1>
        <form id="form_1136056" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>GoodJob - BadJob - Tenerife</h2>
            <p>It's Anonymous. Keep the information REAL. Don't make things up. If anything is EVER going to change, it needs to be REAL information. This form will be sent to an email address and will then be posted Anonymously on Facebook for you.</p>
    </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">What is the Alias you want to use </label>
    <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>You don't have to use your real name - Just remember your Alias for Facebook Comments</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description" for="element_8">Is this about a ...... </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_1" name="element_8" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_1">Bad job</label>
<input id="element_8_2" name="element_8" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_2">Good Job</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">What is the name of the workplace you want to tell us about? </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_6"><small>Type in the Name of the Business</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_16" >
        <label class="description" for="element_16">Where is this Business Located? </label>
        <div>
        <input id="element_16" name="element_16" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_16"><small>Type in the town, or you can find the business on google maps and click on share and copy the link and paste it here.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="element_7">If you want to mention the bosses name, Put it here. </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_7"><small>Type in the Name of the Boss</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_15" >
        <label class="description" for="element_15">If you know the personal facebook page you can copy and paste it in here </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_15" name="element_15" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_15"><small>Go to the top address bar of the boss/owner  you want to tag for this post. Select all the text and paste it in the box.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_9" >
        <label class="description" for="element_9">How many hours a week do you work? </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_1" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_1">1 to 10</label>
<input id="element_9_2" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_2">10 to 20</label>
<input id="element_9_3" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_3">20 to 30</label>
<input id="element_9_4" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_4">30 to 40</label>
<input id="element_9_5" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="5" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_5">40 to 50</label>
<input id="element_9_6" name="element_9" class="element radio" type="radio" value="6" />
<label class="choice" for="element_9_6">50 hours Plus</label>

        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_9"><small>Keep it REAL.     </small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_18" >
        <label class="description" for="element_18">Exactly how many hours do you work? </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_18" name="element_18" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_11" >
        <label class="description" for="element_11">Does your Job Pay Extra Hours? </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_11_1" name="element_11" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_11_1">Yes</label>
<input id="element_11_2" name="element_11" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_11_2">No</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_10" >
        <label class="description" for="element_10">What type of contract do you have? </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_1" name="element_10" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_10_1">Part Time</label>
<input id="element_10_2" name="element_10" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_10_2">Full Time</label>
<input id="element_10_3" name="element_10" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="choice" for="element_10_3">Hourly per week</label>
<input id="element_10_4" name="element_10" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
<label class="choice" for="element_10_4">Dont know</label>

        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_10"><small>DON'T GUESS..This is crucial. Every worker MUST have a copy of their contract. If you don't have one ask your boss or go to the Employment office (SEPE) with ALL your credentials and they will tell you there what contract you have.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_12" >
        <label class="description" for="element_12">Did you get Holiday pay? </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_12_1" name="element_12" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_12_1">Yes</label>
<input id="element_12_2" name="element_12" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_12_2">No</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_17" >
        <label class="description" for="element_17">How much holiday pay did you get? </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_17" name="element_17" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_17"><small>A NUMBER ONLY no symbols or text</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_13" >
        <label class="description" for="element_13">Did you know That there are actually 14 months in a Spanish working year? </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_13_1" name="element_13" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_13_1">Yes</label>
<input id="element_13_2" name="element_13" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
 <label class="choice" for="element_13_2">No</label>

        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_13"><small>Its true, In Spain ins a 14 month pay scheme, where you get a double pay in summer and another Christmas. Most employers will actually incorporate these two payments within your monthly wage...Meaning you get less :)</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_14" >
        <label class="description" for="element_14">Got a story to tell about this Job? Bad or good - let it rip here!</label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_14" name="element_14" class="element textarea large"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1136056" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright Goodjob-BadJob - Visit the facebook page  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/" target="new">CLICK HERE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php.redirect the action to the php file in your server. example mail.php

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
```

and in the php file use these

```
<?php 
$element1 = $_POST['element_1'];
$element8 = $_POST['element_8'];
$element6 = $_POST['element_6'];

$formcontent="From: $element1 \n Message: Is this about a $element81, Where is this Business Located? element6, blah blah blah";
$recipient = "youremail@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $element1 \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Mail sent successfully!')</script>";
?>
```

and add fields from your form. i just added some. edit the formcontent message as you want.

Comment: I am now getting the email sent to me, but the user fields are not being sent.    i get this message ...........Message: Is this about a , Where is this Business Located?, I would like a new line after each element and its corresponding user input if possible

Comment: @SimonJeal Please test if the values are indeed carried to the mail.php page from the form submission page.Try this with each.
`<?php 
$element8 = $_POST['element_8'];
echo "$element8";
?>`

Comment: Also i think it would be best to open a new question with your current code.

Comment: Sorry Mohamed This is above me, I would not know how to start this. Im guessing I would Make a mail.php file and copy <?php $element8 = $_POST['element_8']; echo "$element8"; ?> into it save it. then upload the mail.php to my domain and run it from the form. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `action mailto:youremailaddress.com`

For your example --

```
form id="form_1136056" class="appnitro" method='post' action='mailto:youremailaddres.whatever?Subject=whatever' ENCTYPE="text/plain"
```

Comment: I have done that. But I get my installed email client opening instead of sending directly to the desired email. something to do with send_form_email.php in action

Comment: Simon check my answer

Comment: Mohamed Athif I am now getting my email sent, but form data is empty even the ones you have added